# Why is "ses" considered better than "les" in "Il a ses doigts sur la table"?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

[In the following sentence](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/3219726):

> Il a ses doigts sur la table.

I learned that you should avoid using possessive pronouns to refer to body parts if the subject is clear in the context. In this case, both meet the criteria, I think.

But the comments there suggest that it is better to use *ses*, not *les*. For example:

> the two sentences are correct. And I prefer the duo's

Or

> I am French and How I said, two sentences are correct, but I found the duo's a little more natural.

Why is the use of *ses* more natural than *les* in this case, and how do I know which one to use to refer to body parts?

Comment: I'm confused between your title and your question. Which one did you expect and which one surprised you?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Sorry I just noticed it. Edited. I thought the use of “les” correct since it is about the body parts.

Comment: Your understanding is right, and Duolingo's sentence is the odd one.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Oh, but the two comments on the forum said Duo's sentence is more natural.

Comment: True, but those comments are both from the same guy, whereas another French speaker (as well as, I think, most of us here) disagree. You can even see some tongue-in-cheek comments in that thread ("His or someone else's?" and "Cut off...") responding to what "ses" sounds like :)

Comment: Another French vote over here..  Duo Linguo is sadly wrong there

Answer (score 2):

This particularity of the syntax as regards body parts is just a matter of simple usage and French is merely part of a more général trend, as can be read in the [following](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectif_possessif#Syntaxe).

> Pour les parties du corps, et plus généralement les choses considérées comme inaliénables, le français comme les autres langues romanes évitent d'utiliser les déterminants possessifs et utilisent des constructions avec le réflexif et un article défini.
>  
>   Exemples : « J'ai mal à la tête. », « Je me suis cassé la jambe. » Plutôt que : « J'ai mal à ma tête » et « Je me suis cassé ma jambe. ».
>  L'élément mentionné dans ce cas est implicitement une partie du corps du sujet – respectivement « la tête » et « la jambe » de l'énonciateur. À comparer avec « J'ai cassé mon téléphone. », et non *« Je me suis cassé le téléphone. »

Comment: En 2019, ne devrait-on pas dire « je me suis cassé le téléphone » ? ;-)

Comment: Avant d'avoir compris vraiment ce « en 2019 » qui semble en dire plus qu'il n'en a l'air, je dois dire qu'en aucun cas n'est-il possible de dire « Je me suis cassé le téléphone. » ; qu'est-ce vous entendez par cette date ? Voyez vous quelque chose de plus dans cette forme ? Selon vous exprime t-elle quelque chose de plus que la forme courante ?

Comment: C'était du pur sarcasme, sous-entendant que, de nos jours, le téléphone portable pouvait être considéré comme faisant partie du corps des personnes, tellement il leur semble nécessaire. Je n'avais jamais pensé à utiliser cette forme (incorrecte, je suis d'accord) dans un cadre humoristique !

Comment: @biozic J'aurais préféré faire la déduction moi-même, mais parfois il faut donner sa langue au chat ! Merci de l'explication